# What is the purpose of U's like here 0x01U

Tags: c

I am using stm32f407vg and there is a library called HAL library however there is a statemet or definition not sure to return an error message and it like return 0x00U or 0x01U if certain condition met so what is the purpose of  those U's i wonder ?

Comment: does this answer your que: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029974/what-does-u-mean-after-a-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of U suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`u` is the "unsigned-suffix" and on its own makes an integer constant `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int` depending on the value.

In the C standard, see section 6.4.4.1 (Integer constants) paragraph 5.

Answer (score -1):

It means that it is an unsigned number.

(Looking for some source to update my answer, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix), so this might be a duplicate).