# macro constants with and without "u" at the end of a number

Tags: c, integer-promotion, type-promotion

What is the difference between Usage

```
#define CONSTANT_1 (256u)
#define CONSTANT_2 (0XFFFFu)
```

and

```
#define CONSTANT_1 (256)
#define CONSTANT_2 (0XFFFF)
```

when do I really need to add `u` and what problems we get into if not?

I am more interested in the example expressions where one usage can go wrong with other usage.

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Meaning of U suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix) [What does 'u' mean after a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029974/what-does-u-mean-after-a-number)

Comment: @Sprite This does not cover where one usage can go wrong compare to other one when used with other expression. I am more interested in the usages, do I always need `u` at the end of number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing `u` makes the constant have unsigned type. For the examples given, this is probably unnecessary and may have surprising consequences:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONSTANT_1 (256u)

int main() {
    if (CONSTANT_1 > -1) {
        printf("expected this\n");
    } else {
        printf("but got this instead!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for this surprising result is the comparison is performed using unsigned arithmetics, `-1` being implicitly converted to `unsigned int` with value `UINT_MAX`. Enabling extra warnings will save the day on modern compilers (`-Wall -Werror` for gcc and clang).

`256u` has type `unsigned int` whereas `256` has type `int`. The other example is more subtle: `0xFFFFu` has type `unsigned int`, and `0xFFFF` has type `int` except on systems where `int` has just 16 bits where it has type `unsigned int`.

Some industry standards such as MISRA-C mandate such constant typing, a counterproductive recommendation in my humble opinion.

Comment: `0xFFFF` can be `int` and `unsigned int` on 16-bit systems?

Comment: @IrAM: I meant `0xFFFF` has type `unsigned int` on 16-bit systems just like `0xFFFFu`. Answer amended.

Comment: not only 16-bit systems. 8-bit systems or any platforms where int is a 16-bit type will have that behavior.

Comment: @phuclv: I guess hardware people refer to the width of the data bus where software people refer to the width of the registers used for the `int` type. I updated the answer to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The `u` indicates that the decimal constant is `unsigned`.

Without that, because the value fits in the range of signed integer, it'll be taken as a signed one.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.4.1, Integer constants

> ```
> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which 
> its value can be represented.
>
> Suffix    Decimal Constant            Octal or Hexadecimal Constant
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> none      int                         int
>           long int                    unsigned int
>           long long int               long int
>                                       unsigned long int
>                                       long long int
>                                       unsigned long long int
>    
> u or U    unsigned int                unsigned int
>           unsigned long int           unsigned long int
>           unsigned long long int      unsigned long long int
> ```

Comment: I am aware it indicates `unsigned`, but I am more interested in their usage in expressions where one can go wrong with other.